# jQuery on() event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The first event when clicking `<button id="get-info">` fires just fine.

The second event when clicking `<button id="add-to-db">` does not work.

Could this be a [delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8110934) issue?

**My code**

```
// index.php

<button id="get-info">

<div id="get-info-results"></div>
<div id="add-to-db-results"></div>
```

```
// custom.js

$("#get-info").on("click", function() {
    $("#get-info-results").load("/get-info-results.php", {
        // Some irrelevant _POST vars
    });
});

$("#add-to-db").on("click", function() {
    $("#add-to-db-results").load("/add-results-to-db.php", {
        // Some irrelevant _POST vars
    });
});
```

```
// get-info-results.php

<button id="add-to-db">
```

```
// add-results-to-db.php

Success
```

Comment: That you are _not_ using delegation, is the issue, yes. `$("#add-to-db").on("click", function() {})` only adds a click handler to any `#add-to-db` element it finds in the document the moment this line executes - of which there are none, here in your scenario.

Comment: Have you not added the `add-to-db` button in your example or is it completely missing from your code?

Comment: @JamesS The `add-to-db` button is in the code above. Third code block down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment when you call `$("#add-to-db").on`, there is no `#add-to-db` on page, so jQuery can't attach event listener to it. To fix this you need to either attach event listener once you add element to page:

```
$("#get-info").on("click", function() {
    $("#get-info-results").load("/get-info-results.php", {
        // Some irrelevant _POST vars
    }, function() {
        $("#add-to-db").on("click", function() {/* ... */});
    });
});
```

Or you can attach listener to document and specify matching selector like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#add-to-db', function() {/* ... */});
```

This way handler will be added to document and executed only when event emitted by element matching selector (even if it wasn't on page when listener was attached).

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation and examples. Changing the primary selector to `document` and passing the inner selector `"#add-to-db"` is what I decided to go with. Seems like the cleaner way to get it done.

Comment: @Jeff note that instead of using `document` it is better to use the the closest static parent  to do the event delegation.

Comment: @MarkBaijens Makes sense, thanks for this